# logstash schedules - is it possible to splay the time so schedule does not start on second 1 of every minute?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

simple question here with maybe a complex answer?  I have several logstash docker containers running on the same host using the JDBC plugin.  Each of them does work every minute.  For example:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/bin/mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
        # useCursorFetch needed cause jdbc_fetch_size not working??
        # https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-jdbc-plugin/84874/2
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/10772407
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://${CP_LS_SQL_HOST}:${CP_LS_SQL_PORT}/${CP_LS_SQL_DB}?useCursorFetch=true&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10"
        statement => "select * from view_elastic_popularity_scores_all where updated_at > :sql_last_value"
        jdbc_user => "${CP_LS_SQL_USER}"
        jdbc_password => "${CP_LS_SQL_PASSWORD}"
        jdbc_fetch_size => "${CP_LS_FETCH_SIZE}"
        last_run_metadata_path => "/usr/share/logstash/codepen/last_run_files/last_run_popularity_scores_live"
        jdbc_page_size => '10000'
        use_column_value => true
        tracking_column => 'updated_at'
        tracking_column_type => 'timestamp'
        schedule => "* * * * *"
    }
}
```

Notice the schedule is `* * * * *`?  That's the crux.  I have a box that's generally idle for 50 seconds out of every minute, then it's working its ass off for x seconds to process data for all 10 logstash containers.  What'd be amazing is if I could find a way to splay the time so that the 10 containers work on independent schedules, offset by x seconds.

Is this just a dream?  Like world peace, or time away from my kids?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe rufus cronlines (which is what the schedule option is) can specify seconds.

'13 0 22 * * 1-5' means every day of the week at 22:00:13

Comment: Am I understanding the syntax correctly?  Would this give me the 30th second of every minute?

  `Rufus::Scheduler.parse('30 1 * * * *')`

Comment: I believe that 'schedule => "30 * * * * *"' would give you the 30th second of every minute.